# For each loop through mailto button

Tags: php, html, email, button, mailto

I'm making a button for my website and i just cant get this to work.
What im trying to do is that if a user presses the button all the selected e-mails are put into an array. which is called $FacMail and if u press the button again (Which will change text from select to send) it opens the mail client. The thing is, i want a kind of loop that for each mail address in the array a mail client window is opened, it also pre-fills the subject and actual message. But i have no idea where to start and if its even possible. im using html Mailto. so when i have 3 mail adresses in the array it should open 3 windows (in my case Mozilla Thunderbird).

So is this possible? and if so, how?

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['FacMail'])){
    <a href="Mailto:<?=$_GET['FacMail']; ?>?subject=<?=MAIL_SUBJECT?>&BODY=<?=MAIL_BODY?>><button>Send</button></a>
<td width="18" height="18" align="center" background="images/smallbut.gif">
<a href="<?php echo $url2 ?>" target="_self" class="helpbutton" title="<?php echo Back ?>"> &#8635 </a></td>
<?php } 
}else{
?>  &emsp;<input type="submit" name="select_mail" id="select_mail" value="Select Mail" title="Select the mail addresses"/><?php } ?>
```

This is the actual button. the Form will submit it to another file where the mail addresses are picked from the mysql database but thats irrelevant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. check out the info on asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask we need example code to help you

Comment: Oh right, ofcourse i will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

EDIT: after reading your code, I'm guessing you need another method, this one does not use php. Not needed to load another page to process an array.
Not sure if it can be done from server side.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input class="address" type="checkbox" value="example1@example.com" > example1@example.com<br>
    <input class="address" type="checkbox" value="example2@example.com" > example2@example.com<br>
    <input class="address" type="checkbox" value="example3@example.com" > example3@example.com<br><br>
    <button type="button" id="mail">Open vensters</button>
    <p class="temp-links"></p>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.temp-links').hide();

    // Add mailto link for each checked box
    $(document).on('change', '.address', function(e) {
        var trigger = $(this);

        if(trigger.is(':checked')) {
            $('.temp-links')
                .append($('<a></a>')
                    .attr('href', 'mailto:'+trigger.val())
                    .text('test')
                    .bind('click', function() {
                        // Needed because mailto links can not be triggered by jQuery...
                         window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');   
                    })
                );
        }
        else {
            $('.temp-links a[href="mailto:'+trigger.val()+'"]').remove();
        }

    });

    // On btn click trigger click on all mailto links
    $(document).on('click', '#mail', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.temp-links a').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

This uses [jQuery](https://www.google.be/search?q=jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=wHmiVIO_EeX_ywP-7oKwCw). To fill the subject and message you'll have to add attributes to the link tags etc..

Enjoy!

Comment: No the checkboxes dont have the email as value, you check the boxes of invoices that havent been paid yet, so if you submit it, it searches the database for the e-mail that belongs to the person that hasnt paid yet. So i am bound to use PHP, but thanks for all the effort!

Comment: Why don't you just send the e-mail with php through SMTP or similar?
Then a simple for loop would do the trick.

Comment: Because SMTP isnt really a safe method, and i dont want to use it because some of my clients will probably block Port 25 (SMTP-serverport) because of spam